# How to disconnect git from existing projects in visual studio code?

Tags: github

Currently, all of my files within visual studio code seem to be linked to github for some reason. I don't know how to disconnect these files. Is there a command that I don't know or any documentation that anyone can provide? Thanks!

I have tried looking for ways to disconnect these projects from github and making the text in the file explorer of VSCode to change from green (showing that they are connected to github) to the normal white.

Answer (score 0):

Was this an intentionally created repository? All files will be tracked by default after a `git init`. If there are files you don't want to track, you can create a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). If you have already committed them, you should be able to do `git rm <file>`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Security tab of account.shoppingmode microsoft.com and select Advanced security options to unlink your GitHub account. Unlinking your GitHub account removes it as a sign-in method and removes access to any GitHub repositories in shoppingmode Visual Studio.